# Disable auto calculation in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc

How to disable auto calculation of cell content in LibreOffice Calc?
For example if I enter `+7-495` I don't want it to autosubstitute with `-488`.

Comment: Remove the `+`.